show '+N More' in vue-search-select
I have a Vue component and I am using MultiListSelect (vue-search-select). My problem is, that if I select multiple options, I need to show +N More inside the box.
<MultiListSelect
      :list="list"
      :multiple="multiple"
      :optionValue="optionValue"
      :optionText="optionText"
      :selectedItems="selectedItems"
      :class="customClass"
      @select="onSelect"
    />

The options are coming outside the box.
<template>
  <div class="custom-multi-list-select">
    <MultiListSelect
      :list="list"
      :multiple="multiple"
      :optionValue="optionValue"
      :optionText="optionText"
      :selectedItems="selectedItems"
      :class="customClass"
      @select="onSelect"
    />
    <div class="selected-items-display">
      <span
        v-for="(item, index) in displayedItems"
        :key="item.key"
        class="selected-item"
      >
        {{ item.name }}
      </span>
      <span v-if="remainingCount > 0" class="more-label">
        +{{ remainingCount }} More
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


That one might be difficult to understand without a [repro], do you think you can share something like this?

please install npm and vue-search-select

What do you mean here exactly??? OP already did.
